# Getting Null when calling variable from another class

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I have done a lot of google regarding this and tried many things and have never gotten through. So I have this variable in Class A and I want to print that variable in Class B but the value of the variable in Class A goes through a method before it is called.

```
public class TestSubject extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static String a; 

private void testButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
   a = "hello"; }
}
```

Here I declare the variable and clicks a button to set the variable value to 'hello'. I tested if the variable did indeed get the value by having another button printing the variable 'a' in the same class.

```
public class TestSubject2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

TestSubject test = new TestSubject(); 

private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        System.out.println(test.a);
    }                  
}
```

So here I try print the variable a from class 'TestSubject'.

So what I have tried:

I have tried to use both non-static and static.

I have tried to use a return method

```
class TestSubject {   //purposely left the extend but you get what I mean
public String getString() {
   return a; } }
```

```
Class TestSubject2 {
   TestSubject test = new TestSubject(); 

   private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        System.out.println(test.getString());
    }                 
}
```

However, if I were to explicitly give 'a' a value like:

```
static String a = "hello";
```

It would print out properly in the other class using the first method.

I made sure I click the buttons sequentially so the values are being inputted.

So what I want to know is how can I call a variable from another class.

Comment: are you confirm about this method `testButtonActionPerformed` is called when button clicked?

Comment: Yes, I have another button I click where it prints the variable so I know for sure that the ```testButtonActionPerformed``` was called. I found a way around this, I simply input the variable into a constructor that was called from the 2nd class.